# How to display EMF (MS Enhanced Meta File) image in browser?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, client

I'm looking for any way to display EMF files in (modern) browser.

- use case: opening vsdx (MS Visio) files directly in browser
- it's possible: there are many solutions server-side (php ImageMagic, java, c, c#)
- I found some client side, but not working for emf files: https://github.com/g21589/wmf2canvas

(don't care about IE, Google Chrome for now)

example source and expected (emf, png): [resources](https://michal-miky-jankovsky.github.io/stackoverflow/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 20210304:**

See Lucero's comment; The author of UDOC.js has removed the code from github. Lucero has since uploaded the files as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/avonwyss/570e394a83ed21a75fe0ff5ace989abf). Since the files were originally provided under a MIT license, I don't see a problem with this.

**Original Answer:**

I don't really have a good answer for you.
But I notice in the issues page of the wmf2canvas github repository there is a [discussion about EMF](https://github.com/g21589/wmf2canvas/issues/1).

Where the developer points to [UDOC.js](https://github.com/photopea/UDOC.js) for WMF/EMF/PDF/PS conversion.

Udoc.js is MIT licensed, and  has both a [fromEMF.js](https://github.com/photopea/UDOC.js/blob/master/FromEMF.js) and a [ToContext2D.js](https://github.com/photopea/UDOC.js/blob/master/ToContext2D.js), so it seems between the two you should be able to achieve your goal.

It looks like it is all done inbrowser, without external apis, but I haven't been able to try, since I don't have any EMF files.

There is also a link to an [online demo](http://www.ivank.net/veci/pdfi/), but I can't figure out for sure if they enabled EMF/WMF for the demo, or only pdf/ps.

Comment: seems promising, going to check... ;)

Comment: sorry for missing emf file, link in question

Comment: failing on row FromEMF.js:282

Comment: The author of UDOC.js changed his mind and removed the library from Github. I happen to have a copy so I created a [gist with the files](https://gist.github.com/avonwyss/570e394a83ed21a75fe0ff5ace989abf).